# Big Text file(even a python list can't hold it at all) containing integers as string, can we sort them in Python

Tags: python, file, data-structures, integer, bigdata

First of all, please tell me is this possible or not, I am gone through several posts on StackOverflow but didn't find the answer. I am a beginner in python. I have a file name as `input.txt`.This file is very big in size even a python list cannot hold all the numbers this is why I am creating a text file. Here I have written only a short of it to examine the problem, This contains integers as a string in an unordered manner, I want to sort them. Is this possible using Python? data in the file looks like:

```
intput.txt ="1 2 3 4 5 3 5 7 9 6 9 12 10 14 15"
```

and the desired form is:

```
input.txt ="1 2 3 3 4 5 5 6 7 9 9 10 12 14 15"
```

this file contains the sum of`1,2,3,4,5`numbers taken 1,2,3,4,5 at a time in a series. if we cannot sort this file then is it possible to create a sorted file?

> for actual big file I think the solution is other than using a list!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am using `sort` function of as 'print(input.txt.sort()) but it is giving me an error str function do not have sort attribute.

Comment: If your file really can't fit in memory, this is a much harder problem. How big is it? Is there any limit on the range of values it can contain?

Comment: Yes, its size is 17,112,592,500 and python list max size is approximately 536,870,912

Comment: Actually, I can do this question c++ but I want to do it with python. It is a question from a competition and I solved the rest of part of it I am only stuck in this part to handle a big file.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can use this list comprehension:

```
tex = (sorted([int(x) for x in text.split(",")]))
```

`text.slit(",")` returns:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '3', '5', '7', '9', '6', '9', '12', '10', '14', '15']
```

With the list comprehension you turn these strings into integers and finally you sort these.

You can convert this back into a the desired string using:

```
print(",".join([str(x) for x in tex]))
```

But actually it is not necessary to convert to integers at all since the strings get sorted according to ancii order. Therefore this would suffice:

```
print("".join(sorted(tex.split(","))))
```

Comment: don't forget to join the values back into strings with commas

Comment: means first I have to open this file `fhand = open("input.txt")` and then read its all data line by line right?

Comment: To open the file use 'with open("pathfile", "r") as f:
    text = f.readline()'. If you use windows you have to change the backslashes of the pathfile.

Comment: this helps me thank you, can we write the result in a text file also? this is only a short example of my big data the actual file contains data more than python list can hold can we sort that also by using this way.

Comment: naturally: 'with open('pathfile', 'w') as newfile:
        newfile.write("".join(sorted(tex.split(","))))' would suffice. Be aware that there is actually no need to convert to integers to sort at all.